# Android app Authentication Mechanism for Prestashop

Tags: android, prestashop, webservice-client, prestashop-1.6

I'm going to develop an Android application for my Prestashop. Prestashop provides Webservice which uses a KEY to authenticate/authorize access to web-service. However I want to provide a system which every single user of Prestashop can put orders using his/her user/password pair.
So I want to know how can I check if user/pass entered in my Android app is correct and then provide access to him in the right level or let him put orders on my shop. I don't know the right mechanism. Should I develop my custom module for user authentication or there are some built-in mechanism inside Prestashop for this?

Answer (score 0):

Webservice allow you do all types of CRUD operations. I'm not familar with exactly Android, but I would have done so:

1. Create new Webservice account (get KEY) and allow access to `customers` and `orders`.
2. When customer logged in my app, get password field for his login like

   `/api/customers/?display=[passwd]&filter[email]=customer_email` [(see docs)](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Chapter+8+-+Advanced+use).
3. Compare passwords ( see **/classes/Tools.php** method `encrypt()` )
4. Place order on behalf of this customer into shop.

More here [Using the PrestaShop Web Service](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service)

Comment: A question: customer passwords are generated by concatenation of cookie value inside setting.inc.php and password, so how can I that cookie in my android phone to check if everything is fine?

Comment: sorry, I hurried and made mistake, when customer provide password it gets into DB in next view: `public static function encrypt($passwd)
 {
  return md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd);
 }` we have constant and password values and can compare hashes. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I read again your question, now not sure what do you mean, _COOKIE_KEY_ it is constant defined in settings.inc.php like you said, so if it is your shop - you can get this constant.